# PHP sockets multiple clients read/write

Tags: php, sockets, caching, tcp

I would have a question about parallel socket connections in PHP. 
I'm not a socket expert, that's why I'm asking this question here.
I created a library which is capable to persist data (string/int/float/array/object or anything that is losslessly serializable), like a cache, in PHP. I provided a part of my code, which I think causes the problem, but if you need additional info, visit: https://github.com/dude920228/php-cache

The concept was:

- Create a TCP socket server
- Accept connections
- Read a serialized PHP array from the connecting client
- Call the action handler of the action that is received from the client and do some stuff with the data is sent if necessary or write back to the client
- Close the connection on the client side

It works like a charm with like 25 parallel connections, but for some reason, the clients do not receive the data they should get. At 100 parallel connections, only kinda half of the clients get the data. The program does not emit any errors and the only error control operator I use is at the `socket_accept` call in the main loop. The main loop looks like this:

```
public function run()
{
    $this->socket = $this->ioHandler->createServerSocket();
    while ($this->running) {
        $this->maintainer->checkBackup(time(), $this->bucket);
        $this->maintainer->maintainBucket($this->bucket);
        if (($connection = @socket_accept($this->socket))) {
            $clientId = uniqid();
            socket_set_nonblock($connection);
            $this->clients[$clientId] = $connection;
            $read = $this->clients;
            $write = array();
            $except = array();
            socket_select($read, $write, $except, null);
            $dataString = $this->ioHandler->readFromSocket($connection);
            $data = unserialize($dataString);
            ($this->actionHandler)($data, $this->bucket, $this->ioHandler, $connection);
            $this->ioHandler->closeSocket($connection);
            unset($this->clients[$clientId]);
        }
    }
    $this->close();
}
```

Am I misusing the `socket_select` call there? Or is the problem in an other class? Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: The error suppression operator (@) is almost always more trouble than it's worth.  If you remove it and reconfigure PHP to log to a file instead of printing errors to output it'd make debugging a lot easier.

Comment: @GordonM I log the errors into a file, because I run the server as a linux daemon. The file's last entry was on 8th of June, before I made a release on github. Could it really be the `socket_accept` that causes errors? As I see, all data gets stored (I logged the incoming data), but not all clients get the data back.

Comment: Well it's the only thing I can see in the code that can fail silently thanks to the @ operator, so it's got to be worth trying it without it.